# How to design good looking Web Application

Tags: java

I am a java developer and I am on my way to create a professionally good looking web application, one which has jquery, and fancy menus, well organized css, html etc. I have little knowledge of CSS, html, javascript and other web **designing** languages.

Please let me know how developers create such kind of websites that have good look and feel.

I dont want to use GWT/Wicket/or any other java framework. Just the traditional html and javascript as they are way faster than java based web UI  frameworks.

Also let me know if there is any IDE to easily design the website. I use eclipse. can it be done on eclipse.

Comment: is there a specific question here? Seem to be all over the place how to design a website?

Comment: I have a very bad hand at CSS/javascript etc. now i need to give a finishing touch to my website. What approaches should I follow. What do most people do? i m sure not all the java developers are web designers. So how do they manage to put up a visually appealing site?

Answer (score 4):

What you need first and foremost is the knowledge to wield CSS and HTML correctly. There are a number of books available to get your technical skills on par with what you're trying to do. Some examples:

- [A Book Apart](http://books.alistapart.com/)
- [Five Simple Steps](http://fivesimplesteps.com/)
- [Some Amazon sources](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=bulletproof+css&x=0&y=0)

The *making it look good* part is the one that doesn't have a deterministic learning path. What you need are good examples and a **lot** of time invested in studying designs and making them feel right. I suggest the following:

- [Microsoft's Design Toolbox](http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/) (watch Robbie Ingebritsen's sessions!)
- [Tuts+](http://tutsplus.com/)

There's no "read this book and you'll know what to do" approach here. It is a matter of discovering your own abilities and the way you are able to harness images in your mind and transform them into something concrete that you see on the page.

A good page is a lot more than just pretty pixels. UI engineering and design principles are probably more important than making them **appear** to be professional.

And yes, it can be done in Eclipse. I use it. But writing beautiful sites isn't about the tools, it's about the designer.

Answer (score 1):

Dreamweaver is a product by Adobe that has an HTML builder that is helpful to those who do not really want to learn the markup language and stylesheets. As far as I know, there is no such thing for Eclipse, but Eclipse does support HTML, CSS, and Javascript. Another pretty great IDE that is based on Eclipse but is more web programming oriented is Aptana Studio which is available for free. Aptana has a nice built-in browser preview for all modern browsers, and you can get plugins for all the common Javascript libraries (you mentioned jQuery).